# non blocking TCP-acceptor not reading from socket

Tags: c, sockets, tcp

I have the code below implementing a NON-Blocking TCP acceptor. Clients are able to connect without any problem and the writing seems occurring as well, but the acceptor doesn't read  anything from the socket and the call to `read()` blocks indefinitely.
Am I using some wrong setting for the acceptor?

Kind Regards
AFG

```
int main(){
    create_programming_socket();
    poll_programming_connect(); 
    while(1){
        poll_programming_read();
    }    
}


int create_programming_socket(){
   int cnt = 0;
   p_listen_socket = socket( AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0 );
   if( p_listen_socket < 0 ){
       return 1;
   }      

   int flags = fcntl( p_listen_socket, F_GETFL, 0 );
   if( fcntl( p_listen_socket, F_SETFL, flags | O_NONBLOCK ) == -1 ){
       return 1;
   }

   bzero( (char*)&p_serv_addr, sizeof(p_serv_addr) );     

   p_serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
   p_serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
   p_serv_addr.sin_port = htons( p_port );    

   if( bind( p_listen_socket, (struct sockaddr*)&p_serv_addr
   , sizeof(p_serv_addr) ) < 0 ) {
       return 1;
   }
   listen( p_listen_socket, 5 );
   return 0;
}


int poll_programming_connect(){
   int retval = 0;   
   static socklen_t p_clilen = sizeof(p_cli_addr);   
   int res = accept( p_listen_socket, (struct sockaddr*)&p_cli_addr, &p_clilen );
   if( res > 0 ){
       p_conn_socket = res;
       int flags = fcntl( p_conn_socket, F_GETFL, 0 );
       if( fcntl( p_conn_socket, F_SETFL, flags | O_NONBLOCK ) == -1 ){   
           retval = 1;
       }else{
           p_connected = true;       
       }
    }else if( res == -1 && ( errno == EWOULDBLOCK || errno == EAGAIN ) ) {
    //printf( "poll_sock(): accept(c_listen_socket) would block\n");    
    }else{
       retval = 1;
   }
   return retval;
  }

  int poll_programming_read(){
   int retval = 0;
   bzero( p_buffer, 256 );   
   int numbytes = read( p_conn_socket, p_buffer, 255 );
   if( numbytes > 0 ) {
       fprintf( stderr, "poll_sock(): read() read %d bytes\n", numbytes );
       int fred;
        int i;
   } else if( numbytes == -1 && ( errno == EWOULDBLOCK || errno == EAGAIN ) ) {
    //printf( "poll_sock(): read() would block\n");
   } else {
       close( p_conn_socket );
       p_connected = false;
       retval = 1;
   }
   return retval;
 }
```

Comment: I used extra logging/printf tracing the code (not shown here)

Comment: Why are you ignoring all your return values and condition indicators?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The call to `poll_programming_connect` is outside your while loop - so it most likely doesn't accept a connection (fails with EWOULDBLOCK). So you don't have a valid socket to read from.

You need to wait until you have a connection before calling `poll_programming_read`.

Comment: From the code here, the reading socket is a global variable, so the poll_programming_read() will end up reading from stdin.